# Github actions to publish coverage in coverall always displays "unknown" badge

Tags: github-actions, coveralls

I followed [this](https://github.com/mattn/goveralls#github-actions) link to add Github Actions.
I see the actions are getting executed without any error
But in coveralls.io dashboard, the badge is always unknown.

I tried many combinations in github actions still couldnt get the valid coverage badge.

https://coveralls.io/github/kubernetes-sigs/ibm-vpc-block-csi-driver

https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/ibm-vpc-block-csi-driver

Answer (score 0):

I got where I went wrong.
https://github.com/mattn/goveralls/issues/202

Working as expected when PR got merged